# mysql не захватывает символы кириллицы

Tags: mysql, linux

Даже не знаю в чем может быть проблема. Mysql не захватывает символы кириллицы. При вводе данных в таблицу

```
insert into test1 (t_id, t_q)  values ('Издает звук ошибки неправильного ввода при нажатие клавиши');
```

Вот статус

```
mysql> status;
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi (arm) using readline 7.0

Connection id:          2
Current database:       phone_list
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          /bin/more
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.1.73 Source distribution
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    cp1251
Conn.  characterset:    cp1251
UNIX socket:            /run/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:                 2 hours 15 min 10 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 18  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 16  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 9  Queries per second avg: 0.2
--------------
```

Текущие настройки структур данных БД и таблицы:

```
mysql> show create database phone_list;
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database   | Create Database                                                     |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| phone_list | CREATE DATABASE `phone_list` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */ |
+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table `test1`;
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                   |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test1 | CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `field` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Вставка в таблицу:

```
mysql> insert into `test1` values
    -> ('и раз'), ('Два'),('три'), ('И ять'), ('шесть');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test1;
+-------+
| field |
+-------+
| и раз |
| Два   |
| три   |
| И ять |
| шесть |
+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

С первого взгляда может показаться что все работает. Но это не так,
('и раз'), ('Два'),('три'), ('И ять'), ('шесть') скопировал из блокнота и вставил в терминал, но когда перевожу на RU раскладку, не могу напичатать с клавиатуры 'и раз' просто не вводятся символы. Заметил на символ 'р' ставятся двоеточия ':'.

Как такое ваще может быть?

Сделал еще эксперименты для поиска проблемы

Настроил терминал в utf8. Подключился через ssh. Вот что выдает при вводе символов с клавиатуры.

```
mysql> SET NAMES utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SET character_set_server=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SET character_set_database=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mys
mysql>
mysql> :»Р»лллвы
```

Comment: У базы и/или таблицы стоит кодировка utf8_general_ci?

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar При настройки устанавливал. Добавил в вопрос запросы 'Текущих настроик структур данных БД и таблицы'

Comment: А что означает "не захватывает" ? Как выглядит вставленная запись в таблице ?

Comment: @Mike Когда перевожу на RU раскладку, не могу напечатать с клавиатуры русские символы. Заметил на символ 'р' ставятся двоеточия ':'.

Comment: За ввод символов с клавиатуры отвечает терминал, а не mysql. Так что смотрите настройки терминала. Просто в консоли например в `cat` удается вводить ?

Answer (score 2):

проблема в кодировках

```
 Server characterset:    latin1
 Db     characterset:    utf8
 Client characterset:    cp1251
```

обратите внимание у вас сервер и база на разных кодировках, да ещё и клиент на третей

Comment: команда SET NAMES может быть полезна

Comment: Как правильно сначала установить все кодировки потом создать БД и таблицу или создать БД после установить кодировки ?

Comment: кодировки бди таблиц можно изменить главное сделать это до того как запишете туда данные

Comment: Даже если установить все кодировки одинаковые, то все равно не могу вводить с клавиатуры кириллицу. Ввод кириллицы с клавиатуры не работает. Почему так?

Comment: установите везде utf8 для русских символов нужна именно она, кодировка latin1 на месте русских символов находятся арабские поэтому операционная система или браузер или терминал когда не могут их отобразить показывают каракули. Выясните в какой кодировке работает ваш терминал установите правильную кодировку соединения чтобы сервер считывал и записывал символы правильно.

Comment: добавил комментарий в вопрос смотреть 'Сделал еще эксперименты для поиска проблемы'.  Получаю при вводе вот такую ерунду mysql> :»Р»лллвы

Comment: @zhilenkov А вы пробовали все таки ввод не в mysql, а в другую программу, например `cat` (которая просто повторяет введенное) ?

Comment: Да что-то с линуксом не то '# echo "Это образец текста" > файл.txt

# ls rc.local  ''$'\364\340\351\353''.txt''

Comment: выглядит как запись уникода в шестнадцатеричном виде но символы не кириллические, а расширенная латиница